# Decoding JSON using json.Unmarshal vs json.NewDecoder.Decode

Tags: json, go

I'm developing an API client where I need to encode a JSON payload on request and decode a JSON body from the response.

I've read the source code from several libraries and from what I have seen, I have basically two possibilities for encoding and decoding a JSON string.

Use [`json.Unmarshal`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) passing the entire response string

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err == nil && data != nil {
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, value)
}
```

or using `json.NewDecoder.Decode`

```
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(value)
```

In my case, when dealing with HTTP responses that implements `io.Reader`, the second version seems to be require less code, but since I've seen both I wonder if there is any preference whether I should use a solution rather than the other.

Moreover, [the accepted answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672556/handling-json-post-request-in-go) says

> Please use `json.Decoder` instead of `json.Unmarshal`.

but it didn't mention the reason. Should I really avoid using `json.Unmarshal`?

Comment: This [pull request on GitHub](https://github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/pull/84) replaced a call to Unmarshal with json.NewDecoder to "remove buffer in JSON decoding."

Comment: It just depends on what input is more convenient for you to use. http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go gives examples of using both techniques.

Comment: IMO, `ioutil.ReadAll` is *almost* always the wrong thing to do.  It's not related to your goal, but requires you to have enough contiguous memory to store whatever might be coming down the pipe, even if the last 20TB of response is after the last `}` in your JSON.

Comment: @Dustin You can use `io.LimitReader` to prevent that.

Comment: @Dustin "`ReadAll` is almost always the wrong" I think if JSON is small and about few Kb then it might be better to read it all to release connection. And this is very often so it looks like ReadAll and then Unmarshall is better solution in most cases

Answer (score 376, accepted):

It really depends on what your input is.  If you look at the implementation of the `Decode` method of `json.Decoder`, it buffers the entire JSON value in memory before unmarshalling it into a Go value.  So in most cases it won't be any more memory efficient (although this could easily change in a future version of the language).

So a better rule of thumb is this:

- Use `json.Decoder` if your data is coming from an `io.Reader` stream, or you need to decode multiple values from a stream of data.
- Use `json.Unmarshal` if you already have the JSON data in memory.

For the case of reading from an HTTP request, I'd pick `json.Decoder` since you're obviously reading from a stream.

Comment: Also: by inspecting the Go 1.3 source code, we can also learn that for encoding, if you use a json.Encoder, it will reuse a global buffer pool (backed by the new sync.Pool), which should decrease buffer churn a lot if you're encoding a lot of json. There's only one global pool so different json.Encoder's share it. The reason this couldn't be done  for the json.Marshal interface is because the bytes are returned to the user and the user doesn't have a way to "return" the bytes to the pool. So if you're doing a lot of encoding, json.Marshal always has quite a bit buffer churn.

Comment: @Flimzy: are you sure?  The source code still says it reads the entire value into the buffer before decoding: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L56-L62.  The `Buffered` method is there to let you see any extra data that was read into the internal buffer after the value.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge: No, you're probably right. I was just interpreting your statement differently than you intended. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 9):

I found this paragraph in the Go web programming book. But there is no explanation given

> So when do we use Decoder versus Unmarshal?

That depends on the input. If your data is coming from an io.Reader
stream, like the Body of an http.Request, use Decoder. If you have the
data in a string or somewhere in memory, use Unmarshal.