# How can I make use of offset value in enconding/json's UnmarshalTypeError for better error handling?

Tags: json, go

A little over a year ago, Go added an `Offset` value to the `json.UnmarshalTypeError` type (see closed issue [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9693) for context). The purpose behind the offset value makes sense, but I'm not sure how it can be used when reading a go http response body, which is of type `io.ReadCloser`.

```
// An UnmarshalTypeError describes a JSON value that was
// not appropriate for a value of a specific Go type.
type UnmarshalTypeError struct {
    Value  string       // description of JSON value - "bool", "array",   "number -5"
    Type   reflect.Type // type of Go value it could not be assigned to
    Offset int64        // error occurred after reading Offset bytes
}
```

For example:

```
var body CustomType
decoderErr := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&body)

if decoderErr != nil {

    if typeError, ok := decoderErr.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); ok {
        // Do something with typeError.Offset here
    }


}
```

At the point of the error getting caught, I've already read from `response.Body` via `json.NewDecoder...`. I'm looking for a way to read `response.Body` again, but only up to the point of the error by using the Offset value in typeError.

Comment: Reading up to the point of the error isn't going to do any better, you're just replacing the Unmarshal error with an unexpected EOF error.

Comment: Eventually I'm wanting to use the Offset to obtain the key causing the issue during unmarshaling, but being able to read response.Body is step 1.

Comment: So are you just asking how to buffer the repsonse body?

Comment: I'm already able to buffer the response body. The json decoder takes care of that. But given the offset value (of type int64) I would like to read `response.Body` up to that offset so I can at least know the location where the error is occurring. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8254 for a further explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The json decoder is not buffering the entire response body for you. You need to read that first yourself if you want to print the portion around the error offset.

Comment: I see what you're saying. My question has been answered (see accepted answer below) but this is good info for the future. I didn't realize the json decoder won't buffer the entire response body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to reuse the request body you should read and store the body before you Unmarshal the body, then if there is a JSON syntax or type error you can return a more useful error using the body you previously stored.

Proof of concept:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Hello struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error reading body", 400)
            return
        }

        h := &Hello{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &h); err != nil {
            var msg string
            switch t := err.(type) {
            case *json.SyntaxError:
                jsn := string(b[0:t.Offset])
                jsn += "<--(Invalid Character)"
                msg = fmt.Sprintf("Invalid character at offset %v\n %s", t.Offset, jsn)
            case *json.UnmarshalTypeError:
                jsn := string(b[0:t.Offset])
                jsn += "<--(Invalid Type)"
                msg = fmt.Sprintf("Invalid value at offset %v\n %s", t.Offset, jsn)
            default:
                msg = err.Error()
            }
            http.Error(w, msg, 400)
            return
        }

        w.Write([]byte(`Good to go!`))
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. In my example I used `json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&body)` but here you use `json.Unmarshal`. Based on prior reading (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21198571/1569757) it's better to use `json.Decoder`. Is it even possible to extract the byte array with json.Decoder like you do here?

Comment: @Alex - No. Using `json.Decoder` is beneficial if you want to minimize allocations but that same efficiency prevents you from using the response body again.

Comment: That makes sense. Marked as accepted. You've been super helpful. Thanks!