# angularjs $http post not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, go

I am new in angularjs. I was trying to post some data to the server through $http post. My code could reach the server, but data is not passed. I am using golang for back-end. What are the mistakes I made here?

```
completeCampaign.controller('campaignCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function(scope, http) {
    var Msg = "hai";
    http.post("/server_url",Msg).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}]);
```

go code:

```
func (c *CarController) TestFunction() {
    msg := c.GetString("Msg")
    fmt.Println("Message is: ", msg)
}
```

output:

```
Message is:
```

Comment: you are getting the "Msg" instead of the body in the server probably

Answer (score 2):

Use $ sign:

```
$http.post("/server_url",Msg).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Nope.. Now it is not even reaching the server. I already defined '$scope' to scope.. '$scope', '$http', function(scope, http)

Answer (score 1):

"Angular $http post accepts JSON objects as POST parameters, whereas you are just sending a string" (thanks @Kaushik Evani)

also you have a typo in **http**, try to update your code to this.

```
completeCampaign.controller('campaignCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var data = {msg: "hello"};

    $http.post("/server_url", data).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: can you make sure your Go code is correct?, i mean handling post request in go.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672556/handling-json-post-request-in-go

Answer (score 1):

@Alejandro Báez Arcila's answer is of course absolutely right. Sorry for being a pedantic, but it's not exactly a typo. And also it would better for the OP to know why his POST is not working. Angular $http post accepts JSON objects as POST parameters, whereas you are just sending a string.
So like @Alejandro Báez Arcila has suggested, send it like `var data = {msg: "hai"};` and just access "msg" key on your server.