# Decoding top level JSON array with json.Decoder

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, json-deserialization

Is it possible to decode top level JSON array with json.Decoder?

Or reading entire JSON and json.Unmarshall is the only way in this case?

I have read the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672556/handling-json-post-request-in-go) and cannot figure out how to use it with top level JSON array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use *json.Decoder* in same way as any other json. Only difference is that instead of decoding into a struct, json need to be decoded into a slice of struct. This is a very simple example. [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7moBlYt5wA)

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Result struct {
    Name         string `json:"Name"`
    Age          int    `json:"Age`
    OriginalName string `json:"Original_Name"`
}

func main() {
    jsonString := `[{"Name":"Jame","Age":6,"Original_Name":"Jameson"}]`
    result := make([]Result, 0)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(jsonString))
    err := decoder.Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://play.golang.org/p/y2sKN7e8gf

Note that use of `var r interface{}` is not recommended, you should define your JSON structure as a Go `struct` to parse it correctly.