# Unmarshalling JSON from the http POST request

Tags: python, json, http, go, marshalling

I have a simple server written in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Game struct {
    RID     string `json: "RID"`
    Country string `json: "Country"`
}

func postWaitingGames(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var game Game

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &game)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", game)

    defer r.Body.Close()
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/wait/", postWaitingGames).Methods("POST")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", router)
}
```

And a simple client written in Python for testing purposes. Here's the code:

```
import json
import requests

json_to_send = json.dumps({"RID": "8", "Country": "Australia"})

post_headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/wait/"
resp = requests.post(url=addr, json=json_to_send, headers=post_headers)
print(resp.status_code)
```

and everytime the client hits the server, the latter yields this error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Game
```

I'm aware of [Handling JSON Post Request in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672556/handling-json-post-request-in-go)

Python version == 3.4
Go version == 1.7

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `requests.post()`'s `json` argument, you must pass you Python `dict`, not the json-serialized version -`requests` will take care of calling `json.dumps()` on it. Here you end up having your dict serialized twice.

Also - always when using the `json` argument - you don't need to set the content-type header, `requests` will take care of this too.

Answer (score 0):

So, following some tutorials like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_post.asp) and [this](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), I was getting the **unmarshall** error and I think you have two options using **[requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)** (when content type is JSON):

```
payload = {
    "userId": "so_cool_user",
}
```

**A:**

```
requests.post(url=srvc_url, json=payload)
```

**B:**

```
requests.post(url=srvc_url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```