# FormValue is always an empty map

Tags: sql, rest, go

I programmed multiple methods for my handler which look like this for example:

```
func DeleteProduct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    log.Println(r.Form)
    db.Exec("Delete from  products where Id = "+r.FormValue("Id"))
}
```

The problem is that r.Form is always an empty map, in my delete request I send the Id in a JSON which looks like this:

```
    {
        "CustomerDate": "13.03.2018",
        "CustomerDateTime": "13:30",
        "UserId": 4
    }
```

in the main method I register the handler methods like this:

```
        router.HandleFunc("/delete",handler.DeleteProduct).Methods("DELETE")
```

Why is the r.Form and the r.PostForm always an empty map?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Form specifically this part *"This field is only available after ParseForm is called."* and btw `FormValue` should call `ParseForm` if it hasn't yet been.

Comment: Secondly, and more importantly Form does not contain json data. Form, after parsing, will hold data sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` + data sent as query parameters, if no such data was sent then Form will be empty even after parse.

Comment: See here on how to get the json from a request https://stackoverflow.com/a/15685432/965900

Comment: Not related to your question, but you're opening yourself up to a huge SQL injection attack this way. PLEASE use placeholders in your SQL queries instead of building a query with string concatenation.

Comment: As @mkopriva states you require a call to `r.ParseForm ()` in order to populate data structures with actual values. From other side it would be good to see the client code in order to verify that your are sending properly the url params or body content

Comment: Posting a JSON document is not how HTML forms work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of JSON request you have to `unmarshal` request body before using 
any parameter. 
For example:

```
type ReqBody struct {
  CustomerDateTime string `json:"CustomerDateTime"`
  CustomerDateTime string `json:"CustomerDateTime"`
  UserId           int    `json:"UserId"`
}

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
if err != nil {
    // Error handler...
}
rb := ReqBody{}
json.Unmarshal(body, &rb)
// Now you can perform something like this:
println(rb.UserId)
```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, I understand what you are trying to tell me but how can I access the body?

Comment: @JohannesGnadlinger You can use `req.Body` where `req is req *http.Request`.

Comment: yeah I already thought this would be the solution but I need a byte[] to unmarhal and not an io.ReadCloser

Comment: @JohannesGnadlinger Also you have to do: `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)`

Comment: awesome thank you for your help now it finally works i am new to this language and you really helped me here :)

Comment: @JohannesGnadlinger Happy to help!)

Comment: @JohannesGnadlinger just FYI you don't need `[]byte` to unmarshal the request's body, you can use a `json.Decoder`, passing the body to its constructor func and then calling `Decode`. This is, AFAICT, the preferred method to unmarshal json requests.

Comment: Yes, as another option it's possible to use: `json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&rb)`. Thank you @mkopriva !