# How not to allow empty fields when Unmarshalling json to a struct

Tags: json, go

I do have this struct for my request

```
type RequestBody struct {
    ForkliftID  string `json:"forklift_id"`
    WarehouseID string `json:"warehouse_id,omitempty"`
    TaskID      string `json:"task_id"`
}
```

If I don't send the `"forklift_id"` in the json request body, the unmarshalling assigns "" without returning error, I wonder if there is something like

```
`json: "forklift_id,notempty"`
```

so the unmarshalling returns an error if the field is not present or empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not declare `omitempty` means "notempty", if you expect the "forklift_id" is not empty string, you can define as `ForkliftID  *string json:"forklift_id"`, the default value of point is nil

Comment: I did that, but there is no error if the field is not present, so I want to know if there is an explicit metadata to cause an error if the field is not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the field type to `*String`. After unmarshaling, if the value is `nil`, then you know the JSON field was not provided.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052845/1218512) for a more thorough example of unmarshaling error-checking.

Answer (score 6):

I assume what you did (treating empty value from payload as an error) is for validation purposes. If so, I think you can go with @colminator answer, or try to use 3rd party library that designed to solve this particular problem. One example library is https://github.com/go-playground/validator.

```golang
type RequestBody struct {
    ForkliftID  string `json:"forklift_id"  validate:"required"`
    WarehouseID string `json:"warehouse_id" validate:"required"`
    TaskID      string `json:"task_id"`
}

// ...

var payload RequestBody 

// ...

validate := validator.New()
err := validate.Struct(payload)
if err != nil {
    // handle the error
}
```

The field with tag `validate:"required"` will be validated when `validate.Struct()` called.

There are also a lot of useful validation rules available other than `required`.

For a more detailed example, take a look at [the example source code](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v9/_examples/struct-level/main.go)

---

Another alternative solution would be, by performing explicit checks across those struct's fields. Example:

```golang
// ...

if payload.ForkliftID == "" {
     err = fmt.Errorf("Forklift ID cannot be empty")
}
if payload.WarehouseID == "" {
     err = fmt.Errorf("Warehouse ID cannot be empty")
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and will let you know if it works :) Thanks

Comment: For others: This validator validates structs, not JSON. As a result, the error message refers to struct members with golang casing, not JSON casing. Also, it cannot distinguish between zero values and absent JSON properties.