# How to get parameters in POST request

Tags: http, go, post

I am trying to get the parameters made in a POST request, but I am not able to make it, my code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    fmt.Printf("Starting server for testing HTTP POST...\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.Error(w, "404 not found.", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        // Call ParseForm() to parse the raw query and update r.PostForm and r.Form.
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
            return
        }
        name := r.Form.Get("name")
        age := r.Form.Get("age")
        fmt.Print("This have been received:")
        fmt.Print("name: ", name)
        fmt.Print("age: ", age)
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only POST methods are supported.")
    }
}
```

I am making the POST request in the terminal as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"name":"Alex","age":"50"}' localhost:8080
```

And then the output is:

```
This have been received:name: age:
```

Why it is not taking the parameters? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to first do `r.ParseForm()`, it parses the raw query from the URL and populates the form.

Comment: A am doing that, after case: POST, in the if conditional

Comment: You are sending a POST with json data. Set the `Content-Type` header and use `json.Decode` to parse the data in go.

Comment: Or you could change the curl command to post in urlencoded form, to match what the code expects: curl -X POST -d name=Alex -d age=50 localhost:8080

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling JSON Post Request in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672556/handling-json-post-request-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pass your body as a `json` object, you better define a `Go` struct matching that object and decode the `request` body to the object.

```golang
type Info struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
info := &Info{}
if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(info); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
_ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(info)
```

You can find the whole working code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/IBWyA_LjLp7).

```sh
$ curl -X POST -d '{"name":"Alex","age":50}' localhost:8080
```

This `POST` request is working fine now.

You could modify the `Go` struct and also the response `object` as you like .

Comment: Thank you very much for your apportation, I appreciate it a lot!